# VS Code live server issue with responsive mode/view

Tags: visual-studio-code, browser, liveserver

Whenever I implement any changes to my project my browser stops working (not in desktop view but in responsive view). And then, when I close devtool and refresh the page it works just fine. The issue is mainly in responsive mode/view. Also, I checked and my internet works just fine.

Here's an image of the message that shows everytime when I implement any changes and save:

[image: Here's an image of the message that shows everytime when I implement any changes and save]

Comment: have you touched any network emulation settings in your devtools?

Comment: I apologize for replying this late . The issue is still ongoing . I do not have any deeper knowledge about network emulation . So it's not impossible to messed up in it . Maybe I've messed up somewhere in devtools . Can you help me out to solve this issue . Thank You .